# MVC 5 Confirm Secondary Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have extended the IdentityUser class and added a secondary PhoneNumber a SecondaryPhoneNumberConfirmed and SecondaryEmail and SecondaryEmailConfirmed.

So this works fine with PhoneNumber since the UserManagers methods **VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync** and **GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync** can take a PhoneNumber as parameter.

However this is not the case for Email. The **ConfirmEmailAsync** and **GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync** only takes the userID and token as parameters :/ so how can I verify this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for a temporary workaround I can abuse the UsersManager SetEmailAsync method so I temporarly change the users email and verify it and then change it back :P